# How can I modify php date in bitnami?

Tags: php, date, azure, bitnami

I have read other StachOverflow answers and forums about php and date but they did not help me. I am using bitnami in a Azure server and use date in the shell I get

> Wed May  4 10:25:16 UTC 2016

. But with php `date("d-m-y/H:i:s")` function y get

> 04-05-16/03:18:51

I have changed the timezone from `date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles` to `date.timezone = Europe/Paris`  in `php.ini` file that is in

> opt/bitnami/php/etc

The file is modified I have permission to do it and if I do cat php.ini | grep date.timezone I get ;

> http://php.net/date.timezone
>
> date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"

I have restarted apache with

> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

But the time is still wrong. Besides, if I use `phpinfo()`, `date.timezone` is also wrong: `America/Los_Angeles`

Do I need to restart something more? What more I have to do to get the correct time?

Comment: From phpinfo() you can check which ini file is loaded. The one loaded may be not the one you edited.

Comment: What is the difference between Configuration File (php.ini) Path and Loaded Configuration File? http://prntscr.com/b02tik

Comment: The first one is where the to look for ini file, the second is the actually the configuration is read from.

Comment: So I modified the right file? I can't find the first one the path does not exists.

Comment: Well, you should know which file you edited? :) If it's located where Loaded Configuration File points it's the correct.

Comment: check this: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Comment: I edited opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini I said it in the question. That is the one pointed in Loaded Configuration File. Why is not working then?

Comment: From documentation: The default timezone used by all date/time functions. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this would only work if the TZ environment variable was not set

Comment: What's the PHP version you are using? And can you check whether you have removed the `;` in the front of the `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
`?

Comment: I am using PHP 5.5.30. Sorry I did not understand you about the `;`

Answer (score 0):

Try *date_default_timezone_set()* in the beginning of your script:
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

Hope it helps.

Comment: Now the time is 2 hours more, any idea? I have read that using the date_default_timezone_set() was worse option than modifying the php.ini file because maybe you have to run that function in many places, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, you are right, this was just for fix. Try using echo ini_get('date.timezone') to print out current setup timezone. If it reads wrong, perhaps you edited a wrong ini file.

Comment: That is what I was talking about with @Pavel Petrov but following phpinfo() output I am not editing the wrong file.

Comment: I've a webserver in Canada, used by Brasilian users. Ren answer is the right one. On my main include fle (included in all pages), I have: date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); so you can do the same with Europe Paris. You must also use something like $ret = setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.utf-8"); (in my case Portuges from Brasil) in order that string functions work with the language you want.